# preg_match password validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, passwords, preg-match

I want to only allow passwords that:

1. Contain a-z / A-Z / 0-9
2. Contain 1 letter and 1 number (I test if password < 8 somewhere else in the code)

atm this is what I have:

```
function invalid($pass){
    return (bool) preg_match('Some pattern???', $pass);
}
```

I've searched for an answer, but I just don't get how these patterns work. So I can't modify patterns that contain certain elements my validation needs.

EDIT:
I now have this

```
function invalid($pass){
        if(preg_match("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$", $pass)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But it is denying every password I enter, even: Test1234 (1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 letter, 8 characters)

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$`

This will make it so that the password must include at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, and one numeric digit.

If you really just want at least one letter, one digit, then take out the `(?=.*[A-Z])` part.

Also, for future reference, check [this library](http://www.regxlib.com/) out. 
The regex above came from [here.](http://www.regxlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password)

And for clarity, you'll use it with slashes around it like this:

`preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$/", $pass)`

Or, more verbosely:

```
$pass = "GoodPassword123";
echo preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$/", $pass) ? "Password is good" : "Password is bad";
```

Comment: {8,16} what does this do?

Comment: OH right, forgot to mention that. It makes it so the password must be between 8 and 16 characters.

Comment: oh ok, so I don't have to test if it is longer than 8 in my code anymore

Comment: Yeah, bingo - ! All in one - ! But, it is a good idea to do that as a separate check so that you can give more specific error messages to the user.

Comment: thanks, one last question: when a password is entered that does not match the pattern will it return false or true?

Comment: Try it yourself, and see - ! It will return `true` if the password meets the criteria - `false` if it does not.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work!

Comment: I added another snippet -- run that, you'll see that it works... perhaps you just forgot to put the `/`'s on both ends of the regexp?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $pass);
```

Some explanation:

^ matches the beginning of the line

[a-zA-Z0-9]* matches a string of arbitrary length (can be an empty string) that consists only of chars a-Z, A-Z, 0-9

([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z]) matchs a letter followed by a digit or vise versa

$ matches the end of the line